# Double quotes in PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, double-quotes

I am pretty familiar with PHP, but I am brand new with regular expressions in PHP.  I am trying to figure out how to only allow a-z, A-Z, 0-9, :, ' (single quote), " " (double quote),  +, -, ., (comma), &, !, *, (, and ).

I have found several working examples of what I am looking for EXCEPT how to allow the single quote and the double quote.

An Example of what I am looking for is:
Hello, this is just an example of what I am looking for: "Hello World!".

I am trying to validate a textarea $_POST['suggestion'] using:

```
$errors = array();

if(!preg_match('insert regular expression',$_POST['suggestion'])){
    $errors['suggestion2'] = "Invalid";
}
```

With everything I have tried, I always get:

An Example of what I am looking for is: Hello, this is just an example of what I am looking for: \"Hello Wolrd!\".

I don't understand why the \ are in front of the quotes?

Comment: See Demo https://regex101.com/r/oO7sB6/1

Comment: Re your dupe question you just posted - posting a new question is only permitted if it's a different question.  Otherwise you need to reword your original question to make it clear, but first discuss with the answerer here why their answer does not work for you. Does the RegEx in the answer work for you? If not, why not? (also, deleting too many questions will get you blocked from asking more - this is how the site works to stop people asking and deleting too much). If needed, edit your question and add what you tried from the answer and why it didn't work - just be concise and clear.

Comment: What is the output of: `echo phpversion();` ? If it is <5.4 then take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php And make sure you don't have magic quotes enabled

Comment: the phpversion(); is 5.2.17... If I disable the magic quotes using the the php script it provides AND use the example provided in the answer below, it allows everything to pass... even the ones not included in the regex...if I don't disable the magic quotes, I get the \ before the quotes

Comment: I am confused.  I am custom coding the site, and the only time I have used a .htaccess file is if I used a framework like WordPress, etc.  Also, I don't have access to the server cPanel, so how would I create a custom .htaccess file for this site specifically so I could include the php_flag, and how would I include it onto the php page or would I use the 'include' for that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9:'"+.,&!*()-]
```

Note that the hyphen `-` is placed at the end position so as not to form a range (and it can match a literal `-`). `+`, `*`, `.`, `(` and `)` do not have to be escaped inside a character class. Generally, `^-]` should be escaped, but if they appear at the start of final position in the character class, they do not have to. `\` must be escaped in the character class, but you are not allowing it.

Also, if you want to match chunks of allowed symbols, add a `+` quantifier after the character class: `[a-zA-Z0-9:'"+.,&!*()-]+`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO7hL8/1) here and [here](https://regex101.com/r/wO7hL8/2).

Sample PHP code:

```
$re = "/[a-zA-Z0-9:'\"+.,&!*()-]/"; 
$str = "a-zA-Z0-9:'\"+.,&!*()-"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**EDIT:**

Since you updated the question, here is the [information to turn off escaping double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in earlier PHP versions. As one of the options, you may go to *.htaccess* file and set `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off`.

Comment: @Matt: Could you please accept the answer if it works for you?

Comment: When I try your example, I get:  An Example of what I am looking for is: Hello, this is just an example of what I am looking for: \"Hello World!\".    Why are the \ in front of the "?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exacly you are doing? I just provided you with a character class that matches specific script subset, and the regex matches all of the symbols in the sentence above but the space. Please update your post. Or better post a new question, as this one is answered.

Comment: @Rizier123: I said "post a new question". It clearly is not re-posting the same question.

Comment: The answer doesn't work for what I am needing.  I still get \ in front of the quotes.  On the question I reposted, I got an answer about the magic quotes so I tried disabling them and now EVERYTHING goes through and it doesn't stop anything that's not in the regex.   

I edited the question to be more specific along with the actual code I am using.  I would appreciate an updated answer since the answer that was given did not able to help me.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry for this confusion, it can happen when someone asks for more than 1 thing in a question. One question is a regex that allows some chars, and another question is why my return string gets back with escaped quotation marks. I updated my answer.